# AngularJS : Pass variables in service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to move my login logic to a service.. but I don't know how to pass the login details to the service.

**I have:**

```
$scope.login = function (login_username, login_password) {
    $http.post('/login', {userName: login_username, password: login_password}).success(function(response) {
        ....
    });
});
```

**What I am trying to do:**

**1.**  Have a service that will take looking details and fetch user's profile...

```
app.factory('userProfile', function($http) {
  return {
    getUserProfile: function() {
      return $http.post('/login',{userName: userNameVar, password: passwordVar});
    }
  };
});
```

... But replace `userNameVar` and `passwordVar` with users details, when user clicks login

```
function appCtrl($scope, userProfile) {
    $scope.login = function (login_username, login_password, rememberMe) {
        userProfile.getUserProfile().success(function(profile) {
            $scope.uProfile = profile;
            console.log($scope.uProfile);
        });
    };
};
```

I tried inserting `{userName: login_username, password: login_password}` in `userProfile.getUserProfile()` like `userProfile.getUserProfile({userName: login_username, password: login_password})`

Comment: Inject the service to the controller and call the function of service. You can pass the parameter in that function call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `getUserProfile` function in the service to:

```
app.factory('userProfile', function($http) {
  return {
    getUserProfile: function(userNameVar, passwordVar) {
      return $http.post('/login',{userName: userNameVar, password: passwordVar});
    }
  };
});
```

and then your contoller can look like:

```
function appCtrl($scope, userProfile) {
    $scope.login = function (login_username, login_password, rememberMe) {
        userProfile.getUserProfile(login_username, login_password).success(function(profile) {
            $scope.uProfile = profile;
            console.log($scope.uProfile);
        });
    };
};
```